# Find issuetype name in jira with issuetype id

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

My problem is that I have issuetype number but I need to send it's name into database. How can I get issuetype name having it's number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found needed method on this page :[Jira Constants Manager](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/config/ConstantsManager.html)

I had to use code: `ComponentAccessor.getConstantsManager().getIssueTypeObject(val).getName()`
where **val** is issue number. I had to use Component Accessor to get to correct method.

Import:
`import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;`